# Ordering the Counter keys by month

Tags: python, list, function, counter

So I have an answer that looks like:

```
Counter({'APR': 76, 'MAR': 67, 'MAY': 51, 'JUN': 28, 'FEB': 17, 'JAN': 4, 'JUL': 3, 'DEC': 1, 'AUG': 1})
```

but would like it to be in month order including months with 0 counts:

```
Counter({'JAN': 4, 'FEB': 17, 'MAR': 67, 'APR': 76, 'MAY': 51, 'JUN': 28, 'JUL': 3, 'AUG': 1, 'SEP': 0, 'OCT': 0, 'NOV': 0, 'DEC': 1})
```

My project imports a .csv file with a list of values (there are about 1400 but here are a few examples) and returns how many times the month occurs:

```
year,month,age,sex
2013,JUN,20,M
2011,MAR,29,F
2011,JUL,26,M
2011,APR,20,M
```

and my current code looks like this (I'm just seeing what year10 returns for now)

```
def parse_data(filename):
    with open('case_list.csv', 'r') as f:
        temp_read = csv.reader(f)
        month = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
        year = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
        read, year10, year11, year12, year13, year14 = [], [], [], [], [], []
        for i in temp_read:
            if i[0] in year and i[1] in month:
                read.append(i[0:2])
        for j in read:
            if j[0].startswith('2010'):
                year10.append(j[1])
            if j[0].startswith('2011'):    
                year11.append(j[1])
            if j[0].startswith('2012'):
                year12.append(j[1])
            if j[0].startswith('2013'):    
                year13.append(j[1])
            if j[0].startswith('2014'):
                year14.append(j[1])
        return Counter(year10)
```

Question for context:

You can assume that the file is correctly formatted (ie, begins with a header row as in the above example).
You can assume that each record is correctly formatted, but your function should only count valid records. A valid record is a record that has valid values for year and month.
Valid years are : 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014
Valid months are: JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC
Invalid records should be ignored

Comment: The items in the counter are unordered. You will have to sort them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Counter` objects do not maintain order. However, `OrderedDict`s *do*. You can convert you `Counter` into an `OrderedDict` using a generator comprehension and passing it to the constructor.

```
month = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 
         'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

o = OrderedDict((m, c[m]) for m in month if c[m] > 0)    
print(o) 
OrderedDict([('JAN', 4),
             ('FEB', 17),
             ('MAR', 67),
             ('APR', 76),
             ('MAY', 51),
             ('JUN', 28),
             ('JUL', 3),
             ('AUG', 1),
             ('DEC', 1)])
```

I've added a condition to ignore months for which counts are `0`. If you want those, your code simplifies with the use of a `map`:

```
o = OrderedDict(map(lambda m: (m, c[m]), month))
print(o) 
OrderedDict([('JAN', 4),
             ('FEB', 17),
             ('MAR', 67),
             ('APR', 76),
             ('MAY', 51),
             ('JUN', 28),
             ('JUL', 3),
             ('AUG', 1),
             ('SEP', 0),
             ('OCT', 0),
             ('NOV', 0),
             ('DEC', 1)])
```

Comment: Oh much lord i didn't know this was a thing! Thanks!!! Is there a way I could manual force and add values for 0's ie appending the dictionary if the month is not counted since the Counter will ignore it if there is none

Comment: @AkiraWang Actually, I added a condition to _ignore_ months where the count is 0, but, they are included by default. See my edit.

Comment: Oh yep I see it now! Thanks so much :)

Comment: nevermind this made sense here but when I tried implementing it I only realised it works because Counter returns a dictionary, key list whereas my actual code is in a list format. So currently an shortened example list  year10 = ['JUN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'MAY'], is there a way to return [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0] where it is in order of months? Sorry about that!

Comment: I figured a really long means is making a list [year10.count('JAN'), year10.count('FEB'), etc etc] which will return a correct value but is quite long and looks unnecessary

Comment: C = Counter(year10); And then repeat the same thing in the second bit of code. I don’t see how your actual use case is so different.